# Assigned Objective C property value turns to totally different result

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a small method that assigns value to an Objective C class

```
locationManagerStartDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(0 - lastRunDuration) sinceDate:lastStopDate];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
[cmPedometer queryPedometerDataFromDate:locationManagerStartDate toDate:now withHandler:^(CMPedometerData *pedometerData, NSError *error) {
    int historySteps = pedometerData.numberOfSteps.intValue;
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }
    pedometer.steps = historySteps;
    run.steps = [NSNumber numberWithInt:historySteps];
    run.distance = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:pedometerData.distance.floatValue + run.distance.floatValue];
    double duration = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:locationManagerStartDate];
    run.duration = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:duration];
}];
```

I put breakpoint in every single line in Xcode to check the value change
At line: `double duration = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:locationManagerStartDate];`

I checked the value for "duration" and it is: 324634.92016398907

Then I step over to execute line: run.duration = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:duration];
                }]

And I check the value for run.duration, however, the value turns into: -3046

I have no idea why it happens.

This is how I define "duration" property in Run.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * duration;
```

And this is how I set property in Run.m

```
@dynamic duration;
```

Run.m and Run.h are automatically generated as they are managedobjectcontext.

---

#### Solved

In my code it is not just run.duration's value goes wrong, but also run.steps and run.distance turns into rubbish after assigning a value. I checked their value via either NSLog output or put break point and use "po" command. The problem is resolved by moving `[now timeIntervalSinceDate:locationManagerStartDate];` outside of the block area, after doing this change, both "run.steps" and "run.distance" is able to have correct value even they are executed before this time calculation.

Comment: Do you understand that the debugger is notoriously buggy?  You cannot rely on it to display the correct values of variables -- you must either use NSLog or use `po` in the console log.

Comment: Did you try to check duration.double ?

Comment: Hi @HotLicks the reason being I start doing this debug is app's output is wrong. And I managed to track down and find that line "run.duration = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:duration];" is the problem. So if I simply ignore the debug issue the app wont give me the right output anyway.

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala Thanks for your reply. I checked "run.duration.doubleValue" and it still displays a strange number.

Comment: @HotLicks yes I am using "po" to print the value. The value I put in my question is a copy/paste from "po" result.

Comment: which architecture are you using? 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: Is it possible to share more code with us?

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala It is standard architecture, which contains 64 and 32 bit. And one thing got my attention is the value assign happens in the block as my code provided. "[cmPedometer queryPedometerDataFromDate:locationManagerStartDate toDate:now withHandler:^(CMPedometerData *pedometerData, NSError *error) {...". If I assign the value outside the block it seems ok, but I do need to use the value that is available inside block.

Answer (score 2):

Beginners problem: You don't seem to know what asynchronous code is.

The code block where you are setting run.duration is executed at some time in the future, not right now. If you start locationManager and then check run.duration immediately, you *will* get rubbish because your code hasn't been executed yet.

This is how *all* asynchronous calls work, so that is something that you have to learn how to handle.

Comment: Yes, thats correct! If you are using the value immediately after the block then you will not get the value which you assigned inside the block. The block will be executed asynchronously at a later point of time.

Comment: I really don't feel like to argue, but yes I know block is asychronized code. I understand that you come to this conclusion because I didn't tell you that not just run.duration's value goes wrong, but also run.steps and run.distance turns into rubbish after assigning a value. I checked via either NSLog output or put break point and use "po" command. The problem is resolved by moving "[now timeIntervalSinceDate:locationManagerStartDate];" outside of the block area, after doing this "run.steps" and "run.distance" is able to have correct value even they are executed before this time calculation.

Answer (score -2):

It seems this line is the problem:

```
double duration = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:locationManagerStartDate];
run.duration = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:duration];
```

When I move these 2 lines to out side of the block, everything start working as expected.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and I think people down vote it because they didn't understand the situation. I have updated my post.